# HLSL Dot Product Returning Unexpected Results

Tags: shader, hlsl

In an effort to spare you all of having to navigate my actual code, I have tried to reduce my problem down to simplest form.  I’m unable to produce the expected result while using the dot function provided by HLSL.  In the example I’m including I would expect the dot product of the two vectors to be 26.  When I run this code it will always return 45.  I placed this function within the pixel shader and am compiling using shader model 2.  Help!!!

float MyDotProblemSimplified()
{

```
float3 vectorOne = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
float3 vectorTwo = (3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
float dotResult = dot(vectorOne, vectorTwo); 
//Expected dotResult: 26
//Actual dotResult 45 
return dotResult;
```

}

Comment: Could you change it to `float3 vectorOne = float3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
float3 vectorTwo = float3(3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f);` and try it? I've never seen a assignment without this vector-"constructor", maybe it helps :)

Comment: I posted this problem to a couple of forums.  I found that I needed to create the vectors like so: float3 vectorOne = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};  This solved my problem.  Hope this post can help someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is from another forum:

The problem is the way you're defining your float3's.

Replace

```
float3 vectorOne = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
float3 vectorTwo = (3.0, 4.0, 5.0);
```

with

```
float3 vectorOne = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
float3 vectorTwo = {3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
```

I'm not sure exactly what the () notation does, but it appears to evaluate to the last value of your three (which then assigns that value to all components of the vector).

Comment: or float3 vectorOne = float3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
explicitly

Answer (score 0):

`(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)` isn't [hlsl](/questions/tagged/hlsl)-specific notation.  Rather, it is a scalar expression that uses the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).  Just like [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), the expression is evaluated left-to-right, and in this case results in the value `3.0` This is then used to construct a `float3` from a single scalar value, which replicates that value to all channels.

To achieve the desired result, your options are:

```
// option 1:
float3 v = float3(x,y,z);

// option 2:
float3 v = {x,y,z};

// option 3:
float3 v;
v.x = x;
v.y = y;
v.z = z;
```